# Remove a metabox registered by another plugin - Woocommerce

Tags: metabox

I am trying to remove the gallery metabox which is added by WooCommerce - its been added in an update, but I already have a Gallery metabox, and I don't want to confuse the client.

Obviously I can hack the plugin, but I'd like to do it from the functions.php

I've tried:

```
function remove_my_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images',  'product', 'side');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_my_meta_boxes', 40 );
```

It doesn't seem to work

The code that's adding it seems to be

```
public function __construct() {
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ), 30 );
}
```

and

```
public function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images', __( 'Product Gallery', 'woocommerce' ), 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Images::output', 'product', 'side' );
}
```

I've removed sections which aren't relevant - ie other metaboxes registered etc.

Comment: You could give [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/im8-box-hide/) a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick search in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/247f0ac064f13056cfa6d41ec2c1cf3d6f7a4a4c/includes/admin/post-types/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php#L95) shows the following line:

```
add_meta_box(
    'woocommerce-product-images',
    __( 'Product Gallery', 'woocommerce' ),
    'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Images::output',
    'product',
    'side'
);
```

So your call to [`remove_meta_box()`](http://queryposts.com/function/remove_meta_box/) uses the right id/handle/name as well as the right priority and context.

The problem just is the hook and the priority at which the hook executes - you have to unregister *later* than the WooCommerce plugin [registers the boxes](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/247f0ac064f13056cfa6d41ec2c1cf3d6f7a4a4c/includes/admin/post-types/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php#L26). Else you try to deregister something that isn't yet registered.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'remove_my_meta_boxes', 40 );
function remove_my_meta_boxes()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images',  'product', 'side');
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks! I can't really say I understand it though. Why does the 'add_meta_boxes' make the difference? This is all pretty new to me I'm afraid.

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges That's the hook WooThemes guys use to register the box. `admin_menu` is another hook that runs much earlier, so you're trying to remove something that isn't even registered at that point. `40` is the priority for the callback/action as Woo uses `30` and lower.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to remove that metabox but you will have to remove it after it has been added. I think you are trying to do that with the priority argument but you are also using a different hook and one which, if memory server, runs before the hook being used by the plugin.

```
function remove_my_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images',  'product', 'side');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'remove_my_meta_boxes', 40 );
```